# Why init domain failed to execute shell_exec type though there is "domain_auto_trans(init, shell_exec, init_shell)" in the sepolicy?

Tags: rooting, root-access, 5.1-lollipop, selinux

I'm trying an root exploit on android 5.1.1 and I have gotten root permission with u:r:init:s0 context now. But when I tried to execute system("sh"), it was denied:

```
type=1400 audit(62.480:16): avc: denied { execute_no_trans } for pid=1166 comm="sh" path="/system/bin/sh" dev="vda" ino=349 scontext=u:r:init_shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:shell_exec:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
```

I looked into sepolicy file and I got this:

```
domain_auto_trans(init, shell_exec, init_shell)
```

Is it not enough for this execution? If so, what should be added in sepolicy?